# Setting notification sound volume

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using a `NotificationChannel` to define my app's notification. I set it's sound with the following code :

```
AudioAttributes.Builder constructeurAttributsAudio=new AudioAttributes.Builder();
constructeurAttributsAudio.setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_EVENT);
canalNotification.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE    + "://" + contexte.getPackageName() + "/raw/cloche"),constructeurAttributsAudio.build());
```

When the notification appears, the sound is correctly emitted, but it's volume is set at the maximum and doesn't take into account the sound level set for notifications by the user. Does anyone know how I can have my app set the notification sound level to the value choosen by the user?

Edit #1 : if I copy the code to execute it in the app's body (triggered by a `Button` click) instead of in the `onReceive` method of my `BroadcastReceiver`, the notification sound is correctly emitted at the sound level chosen by the user for notifications.

Edit #2 : strangely, the notification sound level is correct when the app is executed on the emulator! Could the reason be a parameter in the phone's configuration? (They both run under Android 9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the app solved the problem!

Comment: Any idea to update this answer, instead of uninstall and reinstall. Because my app is already live.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code, hopefully useful for you too:

```
 private void setvolume(int volume)
 {
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume, 0);

Uri notification = RingtoneManager
        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
player.start();
```

}

Comment: I just want the notification sound to be emitted at the level set by the user for notifications. Your solution could work for me if it is possible to get this level programmatically. Do you know if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue. Realised it was because I wasn't using the correct context to call `getSystemService`

Here is how I checked to see if I was getting the correct volume:

```
val audioManager = this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
Log.d("log", "volume: ${audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)}"
```

It worked correctly after removing `this` and using `applicationContext`